# Some Characteristics of Tournaments

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone help me to prove the following statements?

> 1. Let $T$ be a tournament with score sequence $<S_1,S_2,...,S_n>$. Let $i$ be the vertex with score $S_i$. If $S_i≥S_j$ (for all $i≠j$), then either $(i,j)∈T$ or $∃u∈T$ such that $(i,u)$ and $(u,j)∈T$.
> 2. Every tournament has a spanning path.
> 3. Prove that there exists a transitive tournament of order $n$ for each $n≥1$.

I gladly accept your answers and comments regarding these statements...

Comment: What are your thoughts on approaching these problems?

Comment: @CalvinLin For 1, i have to use direct proof; i.e., i have to assume that $(i,j)$ is not in $T$ then show the other one. For 2, a sound construction might do (since every tournament underlies on a complete graph). Lastly, PMI might work on statement 3. Are these enough?

Comment: I do not know what score sequences are. 2 can be done by PMI, fill in the gap. 3 is obvious, fill in the gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hints:*

$(1)$ Consider the set $X$ of all vertices such that there is an arc $(i,x)$ in $T$. Now consider a vertex $j\neq i$. If the conclusion is false, what can you say? It might help to draw a picture.

$(2)$ & $(3)$ Induction.

Comment: Where do I apply induction.. on the order?

Comment: Yes on $n$. It may help to draw a picture for $(2)$ and $(3)$ as well of course.

Comment: Oh I see then. Thanks a lot @Casteels !